# compile mysql_fdw for PostgreSQL 9.5 on win 2008r2

Tags: mysql, postgresql, visual-studio-2012, dll, precompiled

I am trying to compile mysql_fdw found on github for PostgreSQL 9.5 on Win Server 2008R2 64bit machine.

I use Visual Studio 2012 with toolkit for 64bit systems.

First I installed Mysql C library. I was using steps provided here and the results were successful for the demo extension

http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/

and I also checked this blog 
https://www.scribd.com/document/40725510/Build-PostgreSQL-C-Functions-on-Windows

I am unsuccessful at building the mysql extension.

I have error at

mysql_fdw.c(186): error C2065: '_MYSQL_LIBNAME' : undeclared identifier

I am at loss at were the bug is. Is there somebody who can maybe kindly provide me with mysql_FDW precompiled dlls for win 2008R2 64bit and PostgreSQL 9.5. Please

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`_MYSQL_LIBNAME` is defined in the [`Makefile`](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw/blob/master/Makefile) (which you are not using with a MSVC build) and contains the name of the MySQL connector library. On Windows that would be `"libmysql.dll"`.

You have two options:

- Use the `/D` compiler switch to define a macro like this:

  ```
  /D_MYSQL_LIBNAME="\"libmysql.dll\""
  ```

  The “double escaping” is necessary because the *value* of `_MYSQL_LIBNAME` must contain double quotes.
- Edit `mysql_fdw.c` and replace `_MYSQL_LIBNAME` with `"libmysql.dll"` (including the double quotes).

Good luck; unfortunately it is always a challenge to build C functions for PostgreSQL on Windows.
I don't even know if mysql_fdw works on Windows (the documentation is rather sparse, and [this issue](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw/issues/43) looks a little discouraging).

Comment: Thank you Laurenz, I added /D_MYSQL_LIBNAME="\"libmysql.dll\"" to compiler switch,  and did change mysql_dll_handle = dlopen to LoadLibrary and dlsym to GetProcAddress but its not compiling. I have errors: IntelliSense: a value of type "FARPROC" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "bool (*)(MYSQL_STMT *stmt, MYSQL_BIND *bnd)"..:(

Comment: Try and open an issue on the Github page.